# How to locate/find element whose ID and xpath changes on every refresh - Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am working on selenium webdriver using java, and I am facing a problem. I have a field on a page whose id and xpath changes every time that page is loaded. Like, when I open that page manually, I can see some id and xpath, but when my test run, the id, xpath has changed.
Example,

```
.//*[@id='dp1445259656810']
.//*[@id='dp1445260051638']
.//*[@id='dp1445260078674']
.//*[@id='dp1445260154173']
```

these are the xpaths that are created every time I refresh my page. How can I locate/find such an element during my run test. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Below is the HTML code for the field.

```
<div class="form-group event-date">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="dp1445260154173" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-
        untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope hasDatepicker" 
        enter-action="datePickerEnter(event)" allow-empty=""
        has-datepicker="" ng-model="eventSeries.newEvent.date" 
        placeholder="Event Date"/>

        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually when ID or Class attributes are dynamic, you need to look for them using: other attributes/by their dependence to static tags.

Here is an example of looking for a "Compose" button in Gmail. It has:
- Dynamic ID
- Dynamic Class
- One static unique attribute

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3" tabindex="0" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" gh="cm">COMPOSE</div>
```

So my xpath would be:

```
//div[@gh='cm']
```

Or imagine that you are looking for a "Send message" button on Gmail. It has:
- Dynamic ID
- Dynamic Class
- One static unique attribute

The HTML code:

```
<div id=":ly" class="T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3" tabindex="1" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" data-tooltip="Send ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬" aria-label="Send ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬" data-tooltip-delay="800">Send</div>
```

This example uses CSS selector:

```
[aria-label*='Enter)']
```

the rule here is, when something is dynamic, look for it by using something static as a reference.

In your case it will be:

```
//div[@class="form-group event-date"]/input
```

works if your div-class is not dynamic.

Comment: Thanks, looked into the code, and found one static parameter that did not change on every refresh.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which elements are static and which dynamic without having to refresh the page?

Comment: what is the right syntax for this, i am getting error. element_home = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class="octicon octicon-mark-github"])

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to fetch it **based on text**. Selenium does allow to locate elements based on text. In Python binding there are these selector methods:

- find_element_by_link_text
- find_element_by_partial_link_text
- find_element_by_css_selector (if applicable)

You just figure out the corresponding ones in Java and head up.

Answer (score 0):

Without more HTML I don't know how specific these need to be but I generally use CSS Selectors to do things like this. Some examples that might help...

A more simple selector would be `div.form-group.event-date` which looks for a `DIV` that has classes (.) `form-group` and `event-date`.

You can look for parents and children using something like `div.form-group.event-date > div.input-group` which finds the same `DIV` above that has a child (>) `DIV` that has the class `input-group`.

You can also look for HTML attributes like `ng-model` from the `INPUT` in question using the selector `input[ng-model='eventSeries.newEvent.date']` or using the `placeholder` attribute with the selector `input[placeholder='Event Date']`.

If that still isn't enough, you can go crazy and chain a bunch of these together to find very specific elements in a specific structure, e.g. `div.form-group.event-date > div.input-group > input[placeholder='Event Date']`.

Try some of these and see if any of them help.

There are a lot of great resources on the web about CSS selectors. Google some and learn more about them. They are a very powerful tool in finding elements on the page. Here's a CSS reference that I use a lot:

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

The articles on MDN are all really good also.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors