# Unable to locate element in LinkedIn using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I'm trying to write my first program with Selenium that logs in into my profile and then search for specific people or companies. Everything work fine until I want to enter profile from search results. My code is here

```
 public static void main(String args[]){

   ChromeDriverManager.getInstance(DriverManagerType.CHROME).setup();

   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

   final String username = "username";
   final String password = "password";

   driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/");
   driver.manage().window().maximize();

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/section[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/input"))
           .sendKeys(username);

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/section[2]/form/div[1]/div[2]/input"))
           .sendKeys(password);

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/section[2]/form/div[2]/button"))
           .click();

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember31\"]/input"))
           .sendKeys("Bill Gates", Keys.ENTER);

   WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember503\"]/span/span[1]/span[1]"));
   element.click();
}
```

It gives me error `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ember503"]/span/span[1]/span[1]"}`.

So, first I tried different `xpaths`and none of them worked. Then I tried `cssSelector` still nothing. Then I tried this

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//[@id=\"ember503\"]/span/span[1]/span[1)));
```

And got another error `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id="ember503"]/span/span[1]/span[1] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)`.

So I discovered that selenium can't find every element that somehow takes time to load on the page. Can you help me understand where I made a mistake ?

Comment: I am assuming the issue is that the xPath changes after each search result even if the search result is the same. I tried to search the same thing twice and got two different xPaths. `//*[@id="ember1823"]/span/span/span[1]` and `//*[@id="ember2048"]/span/span/span[1]`. Check and see if your xPaths are changing? If so this is probably why it is not finding your element.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath changes on LinkedIn after each search even though the search is the exact same.

Top result first search

`//*[@id="ember2258"]/span/span/span[1]`

Top result second search

`//*[@id="ember2460"]/span/span/span[1]`

A way around this would be to Copy full XPath as it should remain the same, in saying that it is a longer string but it works.

First search and second search result full XPath.
`/html/body/div[6]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[2]/a/h3/span/span/span[1]`
`/html/body/div[6]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[2]/a/h3/span/span/span[1]`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still no luck, same error `Unable to locate element`

Comment: This might be of use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215336/how-to-locate-find-element-whose-id-and-xpath-changes-on-every-refresh-seleniu

Comment: Thanks, so what I did I changed xpath to `"//span[@class='name actor-name']"` that  is static and not dynamic and it worked :)