# How to css select this element that needs mean to hover over it

Tags: css, selenium

I want to select 2 elements on this webpage:
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18619684-the-time-traveler-s-wife
but it requires me to hover over the "sort orders" or the "more filters" element first to open a small box then I can finally choose the element labeled "new". How do I find the selector for this? I have tried using inspect element, but this element seems more complicated than the other ones I have done so I haven't been able to find the right one.

I'm trying to select this element so that selenium can target this button.

[Element 1 is Highlighted in Yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pibve.png)

[Element 2 is Highlighted in Yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gomGW.png)

Comment: Using inspect element, scroll all the way to the bottom and you'll see 3 divs with a class name of "prototip". That's what you're looking for. Sorting is in the first one, filtering in the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the element and copy its xPath. Then, pass the xPath to the function

`driver.get_element_by_xpath(<THE_XPATH_HERE>)`

If the xPath of a web-page changes on every refresh, you need to look for the element with their dependence to static tags or attributes. More information on this can be found here.

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215336/how-to-locate-find-element-whose-id-and-xpath-changes-on-every-refresh-seleniu)

Answer (score 1):

Make a javascript file and put this in it

```
(()=>{
    let links = document.getElementsByClassName('actionLinkLite  loadingLink');
    for(var i =0;i<links.length;i++){
        if(links[i].getAttribute('href') && links[i].getAttribute('href').includes('sort=newest')){
            links[i].click();
        }
    }})();
```

Then do:

```
web_driver.execute_script(open('path/to/file.js').read())
```

Replace newest with oldest to sort by newest.

Answer (score 0):

To click on them just do the following. This is it in Python so basically use the xpath and just click on it.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Sort order']/.."))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Newest']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='More filters']/.."))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='5 stars ']"))).click()
```

In Javascript

```
WebElement elem=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[text()='Sort order']/.."));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elem);
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```